# Disable dropzone when form is in edit mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone control on my mvc view.  After a user drops a file they are able to edit the details of the file.  I would like to disable the dropzone feature in jquery during this time until they have canceled or saved any changes to the file name.  Is there a way to disable the dropzone control?